# Проблема с функцией в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class dream():
      def pyat(spam1):
          if spam1==3:
             print("yes")
          else:
             print("no")

spam2=dream()
spam2.pyat(4)
```

Результат:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\new
1.py", line 9, in <module>
    spam2.pyat(4) TypeError: pyat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Вы забыли self здесь def pyat(spam1): правильно так как написал внизу ответ г-н Twiss

Comment: Alban его по моему рано пичкать @staticmethod

Comment: @Александр надо приучать к правильному, а рано или нет решать не мне.

Comment: Георгий ответ который вы приняли не является верным!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Dream:
    def pyat(self, i):
        if i == 3:
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("no")


spam2 = Dream()
spam2.pyat(4)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">

class Dream:
    def pyat(self, i):
        if i == 3:
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("no")


spam2 = Dream()
spam2.pyat(4)

</script></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы определили статический метод, который не принимает экземпляр, в таком случае используйте декоратор `@staticmethod`, например:

```
In [12]: class Example:
    ...:     @staticmethod
    ...:     def do(value):
    ...:         return 'yes' if value == 3 else 'no'
    ...:

In [13]: obj = Example()

In [14]: obj.do(3)
Out[14]: 'yes'
```

Подробнее о `@staticmethod` [читайте тут.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться за что минус?

Comment: тоже не понял за что минус...